/dev/kvm in guest Ubuntu running on a Windows host with hyper-v enabled
My question is an extension of this. Basically I enabled "Hyper-V" and "Windows Hypervisor Platform". I did this because I will create a new VM in hyper-v that has GPU passthrough since VirtualBox's hypervisor cannot do it. So now I have a VM in VirtualBox that I set up to use KVM as paravirtualization and has the nested virtualization enabled (As shown in the images below). However, when I boot it I cannot see the /dev/kvm anymore. When I disable the Hyper-V and win hypervisor platform the guest's /dev/kvm appears again. Is it possible to make my VirtualBox VM use the KVM as its nested hypervisor? I don't want to export the VM and migrate it to hyper-v manager because it's already >500Gb.
KVM as paravirtualization platform
nested virt enabled
all stats of my VM
And here is what features I enabled on my host Windows.
windows host enabled features

Your question is complicated,
you cannot use two hypervisor at same time at same hardware.
"Redhat"say KVM lets you turn Linux into a hypervisor that allows a "host machine" to run multiple, isolated virtual environments called guests or virtual machines (VMs).
You sed when i disable hyper-v platform on widows dev/kvm appear,that does mean hypervisor now is linux, and therefore you can run nested VMs on Ubuntu with "kvm acceleration " using qemu,virt,kvm-cli..
From Tech Science Press "The study’s findings show that KVM outperforms Hyper-V with 12.2% less Central Processing Unit (CPU) use and 12.95% less time overall for encryption and decryption operations with various file sizes.
To verify that the kvm modules are loaded, run this command: lsmod | grep kvm.
SECOND if you got hardware problem or drivers or storage things specify the question . Good luck
